# Form input boxes are tab-able but not clickable Adobe Muse Website

Tags: jquery, css, html, muse

I've recently made a little website in adobe Muse and I'm using their form widget. I haven't changed any of the settings from the default and the input boxes are not click-able. You can tab through them but that's it. 
How can I fix this? I've tried changing the z-values, putting onclick in all the labels and also changing the divs around. 
The problem can be seen at the url below:
`103.4.16.210/members.html`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've a `z-index` value of `116` set for `#u183` inside your `members.css` stylesheet. You can either remove this CSS from the `members.css` stylesheet or add the following CSS at the bottom of your stylesheet:

```
div#u183 {
     z-index: 0 !important;
}
```

Doing this will solve the issue.